# How to pass the line number, where the mismatch occurred in awk, to Shell variables?

Tags: command-line, scripts, awk

I am trying to compare two csv files. I want the line numbers to be stored into shell variables or array.

I tried something like this:

```
   paste <(awk -F, '{print NR,$1}' file1) <(awk -F, '{print $1}' file2) | awk -v var=0 '{ print (($2==$3)?"match":"a[var]="$1); var++}'
```

This didn't work. Moreover 'a' is not a shell variable here. How to proceed with this? Also suggest other ways of doing it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: diff command can compare files . You can check it also  http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff

Comment: You cannot affect the running shell from an awk command.

Comment: I actually need lines numbers to be stored in a shell variable or array whether it is awk or diff. I need to compare a particular field only @Fat Mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**:

With `awk` print only line numbers where there are differences and collect them all in a `bash` array. Instead of using `NR` in the first `awk` subcommand, use `NR` in the last `awk` command:

```bsh
line_numbers=($(\
    paste \
        <(awk -F, '{print $1}' file1) \
        <(awk -F, '{print $1}' file2) \
    | awk '{if ($1 != $2) print NR}' \
))

echo "Length: ${#line_numbers[*]}"
for index in ${!line_numbers[@]}; do
    echo "line_numbers[$index] = ${line_numbers[index]}"
done
```

**Example**:

```
> awk '{print NR": "$0}' file1
1: aab
2: b
3: bcbaa
4: ab
5: bb
6: ca
7: ba
8: abacb
9: bccaba

> awk '{print NR": "$0}' file2
1: aab
2: z
3: bcbaa
4: yyz
5: y
6: yx
7: ba
8: abacb
9: z

> bash main.bash
Length: 5
line_numbers[0] = 2
line_numbers[1] = 4
line_numbers[2] = 5
line_numbers[3] = 6
line_numbers[4] = 9
```